# illegal inheritance, how to design my hierarchy to create my UnitSpec

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm trying to create a BaseSpec class for my unit testing like so:

```
abstract class FunSpecBase extends FunSpec with BeforeAndAfter

trait GuiceBase extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
    bind[userDao].to[UserDaoImpl]
    // more here
  }
}

abstract class UnitBase extends FunSpecBase with GuiceBase

class UnitSpec extends UnitBase
```

When I run my test in sbt I get the error:

```
illegal inheritance; superclass FunSpecBase
[error]  is not a subclass of the superclass ScalaModule
[error]  of the mixin trait GuiceBase
[error] abstract class UnitBase extends FunSpecBase with GuiceBase
[error]                                                  ^
[error] one error found
```

**Is it possible to work around this scenerio?**

Comment: What's `ScalaModule`?

Comment: @ggovan https://github.com/sptz45/sse-guice java guice scala wrapper.

Comment: ScalaModule is a class, FunSpec is a class. You can't inherit from two classes. [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you want:

```
trait GuiceBase extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
    // bind[userDao].to[UserDaoImpl]
    // more here
  }
}

abstract class UnitBase extends GuiceBase with FunSpecLike

class UnitSpec extends UnitBase
```

Comment: FunSpec is a class not a trait.

Answer (score 0):

Scala allows traits to be extended from a class in order to restrict which classes are then allowed to extend this particular trait. The error:

```
illegal inheritance; superclass FunSpecBase
[error]  is not a subclass of the superclass ScalaModule
[error]  of the mixin trait GuiceBase
[error] abstract class UnitBase extends FunSpecBase with GuiceBase
[error]                                                  ^
[error] one error found
```

is saying that FunSpecBase is not allowed to mixin GuiceBase(trait extending class) because FunSpecBase  does not extend ScalaModule(base class for GuiceBase) . The solution hence is to extend FunSpecBase with ScalaModule or its subclass.